# Custom sorting tuples

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

I am attempting to sort a list of tuples (the items from a dictionary if you must know). The first element is a lower case letter and the second is an integer. I want to sort by the second element in descending order. To break ties, I will use alphabetic order of the first element. So far I have

```
sorted_c = sorted(c.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

This sorts by the second element of each tuple as I want. How do I tweak this to break ties?

**Example input:**

```
[ ('b', 5), ('c', 10),('a', 27), ('a', 5) ]
```

**Expected output:**

```
[('a', 27), ('c', 10), ('a', 5), ('b', 5) ]
```

Comment: what should *breaking ties* give in such case? Have some input example and predicted/expected output?

Comment: something like: `sorted_c = sorted(c.items(), key=(operator.itemgetter(1),int(operator.itemgetter(0)), reverse=True)` maybe?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Doesn't `key` have to be callable?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest On my phone right now. Will update question with sample input and output when at my computer a little later.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Updated question with example input and expected output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to sort list of tuples, you may use *lambda expression* as key to sorted function as:

```
>>> my_list = [('a', 7), ('c', 10), ('b', 5), ('a', 5) ]
>>> sorted(my_list, key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
[('c', 10), ('a', 7), ('a', 5), ('b', 5)]
```

Explanation:

```
lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])
#           ^      ^ sort in ascending order for value at `0`th index
#           ^ sort in descending order for value at `1`st index
```

For converting the `dict` to list of tuples, you need to call `dict.items()` as:

```
>>> my_dict = {'a': 5, 'c': 10, 'b': 5}
>>> my_dict.items()
[('a', 5), ('c', 10), ('b', 5)]
```

Comment: This looks like it will work. I didn't think about negating the integer in order to get reverse ordering while keeping the alphabetic ordering for the letters.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Aww...you deleted your example. I could have used that for my question edit. Oh well, off to make my own example.

Comment: you can copy the one above. It's the same.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Thanks.